# Source for Jews' dispersion in order to sanctify trait of country where they live

Tags: golus-exile

I remember hearing that the Jews were sent into exile so that we can use the strength of each nation.

For example, German Jews being punctual. British people being more traditional.

Would you be able to tell me the sources for this idea?

Answer (score 3):

[Rabbi Gedalia Shor](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50808&st=&pgnum=42) brings from the sefas emes that each nation has a portion of torah that the jewish people took while in galus.[image]

Comment: Very nice. I heard this idea this week from Rav Glatstein shlita, but did not find it. What a hashgacha pratis :). What does he means with: בכל אומה יש אתה ניצוצין ויש חלק בתורה?